# Can CIImage be convert to vector graphic?

Tags: ios

I tried many ways but failed. Such as PDF or SVG, all are nil.
CoreImage cannot export as vector graphics on iOS? 
Any guidance is appreciate.

Comment: From raster to vector? I don't believe so.

Answer (score 1):

No. Core Image is a framework for working with raster images.

Answer (score 0):

A CIImage can definitely be converted to a vector graphic but probably not out of the box with core image. There are libraries such as opencv and others that can process and vectorize a bitmap image. Your results may vary based on your source image and intended output.